# Best way to backup and restore the databases of a Drupal 7 multisite using Drush?

Tags: drush, multi-sites, deployment, subsites

I'm looking for an easy way to backup (and if needed restore) the databases of a Drupal multisite using Drush.

**Drush command I use to backup all the databases:**

```
drush @sites sql-dump --result-file --gzip
```

The backup of the databases seems to work. After executing the above command, databases are automatically stored in /root/drush-backups/*DATABASENAME*/*TIMESTAMP*/*DATABASENAME_TIMESTAMP*.sql.gz

What command can I use to restore the last backup of the databases automatically?

What is the best way to backup and restore the databases of a Drupal 7 multisite using Drush?

PS: I'm using Git, so I only need to backup databases.

Many thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 4):

This is how I do the restore on a site-by-site basis:

```
drush @site1 sql-drop -y && gunzip -c /path/to/backup/file1 | drush @site1 sql-cli
```

You could maintain a list of site aliases to database name and write a shell script to automate the process.

The database name for an individual site could be extracted as follows:

```
drush status @site1 --fields=db-name --field-labels=0
```

Unfortunately, there's no all-in-one solution for restore.

An alternate solution would be to use the [Backup and Migrate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate), which has drush integration. There are `bam-backup` and `bam-restore` commands which might be easier to work with.

As @Duncanmoo mentioned, it's also good to run `drush rebuild-registry` after the restore.

Comment: You may need to first drop the existing tables: `drush @site sql-drop -y && drush @site sql-cli < ~/db.sql`.(Drush knows what user and DB to work with based on the site you are working on). **BTW** Good idea to do a `drush rebuild-registry` after restoring the DB.

Comment: Good idea, I'll include the `sql-drop`.